# Validation error: Attribute onfocusout not allowed on element input at this point

Tags: html, validation, onfocusout

I want to make use of "onfocusout" at an input element. Unfortunately my validators return the following error message: "Attribute onfocusout not allowed on element input at this point."

The html code looks like this:

```
<div  class="form-group">
  <label  for="dbHost"  class="control-label col-sm-4">DB-Server</label>
  <div  class="col-sm-10">
    <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="dbHost" name="dbHost" onfocusout="validateForm();" value="db">
  </div>
<div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: The onfocusout event may not work as expected in Chrome, Safari and Opera 15+ using the JavaScript HTML DOM syntax. **However, it should work as an HTML attribute and by using the addEventListener() method (See syntax examples below).**

> In JavaScript, using the addEventListener() method:

```
object.addEventListener("focusout", myScript);
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp)